# Javascript isn´t precompiled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I´m testing my Rails 3 application in production mode after precompile my assets, but in some pages, where I have custom js files declared I have this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (js/jquery.dataTables.js isn't precompiled):
55: 
56: 
57: <% content_for :head do %>
58:     <%= javascript_include_tag 'js/jquery.dataTables' %>
59:     <%= javascript_include_tag 'js/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap' %>
60:     <%= javascript_include_tag 'configure_sort_datatable' %>
61: <% end %>
```

These files are there. What could be happen?

This is my production.rb configuration:

```
config.cache_classes = true
config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.compress = true
config.assets.compile = false
config.assets.digest = true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Rails 3.2 you have to tell Sprockets explicitly which additional libraries it has to precompile.

```
#config/application.rb
config.assets.precompile += %w(js/jquery.dataTables.js js/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap.js configure_sort_datatable.js)
```

By default it is:

```
[ Proc.new{ |path| !File.extname(path).in?(['.js', '.css']) }, /application.(css|js)$/ ]
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets